# Does Cloudflare accelerates websockets?

Tags: cloudflare

1. Will Cloudflare accelerate my websocket data transfer speed by default (without any additional configurations)?
2. What paid and free configurations can I use to improve my websocket connection? Will Argo help here?
3. What level of performance increase should I wait from these different configurations?

p.s. I know that CDN mostly concentrates about optimizing serving of static content but still I am curious **will it help at least a bit with dynamic content**?

Comment: "Accelerate" as opposed to what? It can't *cache* the data or impersonate/replace your server, so at best it will proxy the connection through to your server. That *may* be a slightly better network path than you would have otherwise, or it may be slightly worse than a direct connection. Either way, your server's processing time will probably remain the bottleneck.

Comment: I know, but I have heard that Argo can help with its Smart Routing. Can this [Smart Routing](https://www.cloudflare.com/products/argo-smart-routing/) help with WebSocket packets delivery time or not?

Answer (score 1):

CDNs accelerate static content that can be cached and distributed to servers with different geolocations. But Websockets are used to server dynamic content, so the limiting factor there is the power of the server and its geolocation.

So Cloudflare or any other CDN are not be able to accelerate websockets in the same way as they can do with static content, well yes Argo might help in certain cases. But the really limiting/problematic factor with WebSockets is your application/setup handling the requests.

There are however certain conditions under which Cloudflare can accelerate connection. Some ISP want to have extra money for better routing (Double Paid Traffic), and some data center owners refuse to pay those additional money.

So it might be that the none payed connection is slower then a routing using Cloudflare as a proxy, under the condition the Cloudflare pays for the better routing. But then its not the technical part of Cloudflare that accelerates the connection, but the contract. You might need to ask your hoster about that case.

Comment: Yeah, I know that in the end the communication is made between my origin and the client, but I was asking **Will it help at least a bit or not at all?**

Comment: @PetroKoval it can, it basically depends one the contracts your hoster has with the backbones and for peering. If those are already good, then cloud flare can't do that much. If you start your businesses with a small root/vserver, then it might be indeed noticeable. But only under the assumption that the routing from your server to cloud flare is in average better then the one directly to your customer. Some ISPs want to have extra money from Server Hoster to get premium routing. And if our Hoster does not pay that but clouflare does, then this might accelerate connections to this ISP.

Answer (score 0):

Note that Cloudflare will reset the websocket connections now and then:

“*Logs from tcpdump show that Cloudflare sends a TCP reset after 1-5 minutes, despite both client and server being in sync on packets sent in each direction*” - https://community.cloudflare.com/t/websockets-disconnected-in-aws-tokyo/44680

“*If you’re intending to use CF websockets, be prepared for random (and potentially massive) connection drops, and be sure you’re architected to handle these disconnects gracefully. Cloudflare rolling restarts have caused hundreds of thousands of websocket connections to be disconnected in a matter of minutes for us”; “when terminating a WebSocket connection due to releases CloudFlare now signals this action to both client and origin server by sending the 1001 status code*” - https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=11638081

“*When Cloudflare releases new code to its global network, we may restart servers, which terminates WebSockets connections*” - https://support.cloudflare.com/hc/en-us/articles/200169466-Using-Cloudflare-with-WebSockets#12345687

So to answer your question, Argo Smart Routing inside Cloudflare can, in theory, accelerate the websocket connections and make them more reliable. But we also know for a fact that it will lead to regular websocket disconnects.

Maybe use Cloudflare for backup connections, to improve the total resilience in the face of [routing anomalies](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/home/amislove/publications/ePOST-EuroSys.pdf).